# FpML Custom binding jaxb

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I'm required to use FpML in my project and struggling with generating Java class by JAXB:

```
[ERROR] Element "{http://www.fpml.org/FpML-5/confirmation}tradeId" shows up in more than one properties.
line 1142 of file:/D:/FpML/schema/fpml/5-5/confirmation/fpml-doc-5-5.xsd
```

fpml-doc-5.5.xsd is imported into the master schema.

I tried to use inline custom binding (I gave up using an external file) as follows:

```
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:ecore="http://www.eclipse.org/emf/2002/Ecore" xmlns="http://www.fpml.org/FpML-5/confirmation" xmlns:fpml-annotation="http://www.fpml.org/annotation" targetNamespace="http://www.fpml.org/FpML-5/confirmation" ecore:documentRoot="FpML" ecore:nsPrefix="conf" ecore:package="org.fpml.confirmation" version="$Revision: 10163 $" elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified"
        xmlns:jaxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb" 
        xmlns:xjc="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/xjc" 
        jaxb:version="1.0">
....


    <xsd:element name="issuer" type="IssuerId"></xsd:element>
      <xsd:element name="tradeId" type="TradeId">
        <xsd:annotation>
           <xsd:appinfo>
                    <jaxb:property name="tradeIdentifierId"/>
           </xsd:appinfo>
        </xsd:annotation>
      </xsd:element>
```

The same error still occurs.

Directly editing the schema to rename tradeId would solve the issue but I can't do that. I still can define my own inline binding though.

Can you please shed some light?

Comment: Just wondering if following link will help. 

http://www.stephennimmo.com/generate-java-objects-for-fpml-using-jaxb-and-maven-the-easy-way/

Comment: unfortunately it doesn't help. I'm not using maven so cannot try the jaxb maven plugin. And his binding file doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Use JAXB version 2. I'm using jaxb-xjc 2.1.13 without issues for FPML 5.5 confirmation.

Comment: Did you use a bindings file? Do you have the following statement in any of your generated sources? You are getting this "catch-all" property because of the following reason